# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline: How can I increment the assembly version only for the changed assemblies?

Tags: .net, tfs, build, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

I have a build pipeline in **Azure DevOps** and I would like to increment the version of my assemblies with each change in the project. In the current build definition the version of the assemblies will increase with each build for all projects/assemblies.

So when I merge the dev branch to the main branch (reverse integration) the trigger runs a build on an agent and it will increase the version number for all projects in the main branch.

### Project Types

The project types are **.NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard**

Is there a way to increase the version number for the changed projects/assemblies only?

Comment: Usually for things that need to version independently I would give them their own builds. Then have a separate pipeline that collects them all into a single "release". The version number is usually an environment variable passed into the build. So you would in any case need to build different projects with different parameters within the same pipeline or stop using pipeline version numbers and instead have each project calculate/determine it's own version.

Comment: How did you set updating the version number?

Comment: Currently we still updating the version number with each merge manually

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes, I look for the changed files in the project and for these projects I increase the version number and merge this to the main branch. I don't want to change the version number for all projects, only for the changed projects. Is there a way to automate this in the build pipleline from the microsoft team foundation server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no default way to increase the assembly version only for the changed project. You could try @MartinSGill's workaround, for the situation that need to version independently you could give them their own builds. Then have a separate pipeline that collects them all into a single "release".

Here is an useful extension for your reference:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task